# How to convert String to a file Name

Tags: java, string, file, jfilechooser

```
  public class saveButtonListener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
         JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser();

          String s=(String)searchedResultArea.getSelectedValue();// ??? 
    }
  }
  Object s=searchedResultArea.getSelectedValue();
```

I have developed a program that saves the filename of the some pictures that user specifies on a file and displays them in a JList. I have save them in this format

```
   E:\something\something\something.jpg
```

Now I need to open that picture using this value. My problem is that I am not able to convert this String into proper file naming that java uses like

```
    E:\\something\\something\\something.jpg
```

I hope you got the point. I need two backslashes. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"\" is used to escape "\" character in **source code**. Path separator on Windiows is still "\". If you got path from user input, then nothing to do here.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to convert it to anything. The string is fine with just one slash. You need the 2nd slash only if you type it manually in the code.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the proper way to represent filenames is with "forward" slashes ('/'), and that will work independently of your operating system. "Backslash" ('\') is a Windows anomaly which should be ignored when handling files in Java.

So, just use "forward slashes".

To convert the filenames, do

```
filename = filename.replaceAll("\\", "/");
```

(You need double backslash because single backslash is used in Java for escaping special characters)

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't this work:

```
String fileName = // from JList
File f = new File(fileName);
```

Comment: File file = new File(searchedResultArea.getSelectedValue());        I tried this but this does not work. Which method should I use?